# Ant java task output is truncated (Windows fork=true)

Tags: java, ant

I have an Ant build file that builds and executes a Java program. The execution is done with `fork=true`, however this causes the console output of the program to be truncated randomly. I have tried adding an extra `System.out.flush()` to the end, but it still gets truncated.

I wanted `fork=true` because it makes it easier when the program uses `System.exit(1)` to report errors.

I am running on Windows, if that matters. Should the `fork=true` option for a java task in ant work on Windows? Do I need to log to a file if I want to see all of the output? Can I tell Ant to wait longer for the forked process to complete?

**Update:**

If I don't use `fork=true` and I use `System.exit(1)`, then I get an exception like this in ant:

```
     [java] Unexpected internal compiler error: org.apache.tools.ant.ExitException: Permission ("java.lang.RuntimePermis
sion" "exitVM") was not granted.
     [java] org.apache.tools.ant.ExitException: Permission ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "exitVM") was not granted.
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.types.Permissions$MySM.checkExit(Permissions.java:194)
     [java]     at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:107)
     [java]     at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:971)
...
```

Comment: Did you set spawn=true?

Comment: So, are you trying to have ant fire off another program and then exit? Or are you trying to run another program, capture the results and evaluate / fail/success to cause the ant build to fail based on the result?

Comment: If you want the build to exit if a java program exits with a non-zero value, you should mention failonerror="true"

Comment: I did not do `spawn=true`, should I? I am trying to build a project for a compilers class where the program is expected to return 1 if an error occurred (so I use `System.exit(1)`). The output is not used for further Ant tasks.

Comment: @svasa Hmm maybe failonerror actually works even though this is the last task I'm executing. Does that cause Ant to wait for the forked process to complete?

Comment: I don't understand why you set fork=true ? you said _"it makes it easier when the program uses `System.exit(1)` to report errors"_ but if you set `fork=false` and your program uses `System.exit(0)` when success and `System.exit(1)` in case of errors, ant build process will respectively end with **BUILD SUCCESSFUL** and **BUILD FAILED**. Isn't it what you expect ?

Comment: @P.A.Cros The problem is if I do that, I get an `org.apache.tools.ant.ExitException`, see the edit above.

Comment: Strange, I have tested it , and it work for me: ant build is ended with a single **BUILD FAILED** message followed by **..../build.xml:14: Java returned:1**, no stack trace. (I'm using ant 1.9.4 and JDK 1.8).